# Аргументы по умолчанию равны "None" и если не записать одну то надо чтобы вместо "None" было просто пустой пробел

Tags: python, filter

```
class Book:
    def __init__(self, title = None, author = None, edition = None):
        self.title = title
        self.author = author
        self.edition = edition

    def display(self):
        #a = self.edition
        #if filter(None.__ne__, a):
        #   a = ' '
        print("%-30s%-20s%5s" % ("Title", "Author", "Edition"))
        print('-'*58)
        print("%-30s%-20s%5s" % (self.title, self.author, self.edition ))

book = Book('Mobi-Dick', 'Melville', '1851')
book.display()
```

Comment: Пробовал поставить фильтр но я с этим еще не разобрался.

Comment: Вариант вместо None аргумент по-умолчанию сделать пустую строку не подходит?

Comment: None обязательно!

Comment: Тогда опишите подробнее условие. `если не записать одну` - если ни один аргумент не заполнен? `то надо чтобы вместо “None” было просто пустой пробел` - записать во все три поля? "пустой пробел" - это пробел или пустая строка?

Comment: что значит `"надо, чтобы было..."` - чтобы было где? при выводе на печать или в переменных класса?

Comment: Да, при выводе на печать

Comment: Если один или несколько аргументов не заполнены (простите за путаницу, первый раз задаю вопрос)

Comment: Воспользуйтесь функцией наподобие `def nn(arg): return "" if arg is None else arg` при выводе на печать ;)

Comment: Спасибо MaxU, помогли